# How to download Buffers as PDF files in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have tried to download the buffers with Blob() here

```
.then(res=> {
      res.data.map(data=> {
          const blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          const a = document.createElement('a')
          a.setAttribute('href', url)
          a.setAttribute('download', 'mypdf.pdf')
          document.body.appendChild(a)
      })
  })
```

, but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can provide the console output ?

Comment: Error
Failed to load PDF document.  And also is not a console error, the function generates the PDF and this is the error I get when the file is opened in the browser